# How to linear interpolate THREE.Object3d()'s rotation value?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to linear interpolate a player(`THREE.Object3d()`)'s position and rotation value to the desired ones(`THREE.Vector3()`).

Here's my code:

```
player.position.lerp(desiredPosition, 0.2);
player.rotation.lerp(desiredRotation, 0.2);
```

But I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: player.rotation.lerp is not a function

I know there is a `player.quaternion.slerp()` function but is there a way to interpolate the `x, y, z` rotation values without using the quaternion?

If there isn't, how can I convert the desiredRotation(`THREE.Vector3()`) to `THREE.Quaternion()` so I can use the `slerp()` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the desiredRotation(THREE.Vector3())

`Object3D.rotation` is not of type `THREE.Vector3` but `THREE.Euler`. Use [Quaternion.setFromEuler()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Quaternion.setFromEuler) to set a quaternion value from euler angles.

Comment: Thank you. So the `THREE.Euler` doesn't have the `lerp()` function? That's why I need to convert to quaternion?

Comment: No, `THREE.Euler` has not `lerp()` method. I suggest you read some existing resources about spherical linear interpolation to understand why you should always use quaternions for this task.

Answer (score 3):

In short.. I generally trend away from interpolating Euler angles.. because there isn't enough information to lerp 2 states with an euler rotation.. how do decide if the angle should rotate from 2*PI across the zero boundary, and not the other way around? You can assume shortest distance, and make that work with some code to handle the direction of lerp but it's often tricky when the desired angle becomes large.. and also suffers from problems like gimbal lock.

This is where Quaternions are useful because it can consistently tween between 2 rotations via shortest distance without the problems of euler angles.

So one solution as indicated by mugen, is to use Quaternion.setFromEuler() with your start and end Eulers, .slerp between them then use Euler.fromQuaternion to convert back the result?